# issue with array declaration in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to create a bash script to pick a random radio ip to make mplayer play:

```
#!/bin/sh
#A simple script to run random radio channels on mplayer

radio = (http://162.253.40.181:8808 http://195.154.69.121:8000 http://108.163.197.114:8103 http://216.245.201.73:9910 http://5.63.145.172:7090)

current = echo $[ 1 + $[ RANDOM % 5 ]]

#echo $current

mplayer $radio{[current]}
```

I think my array declaration is wrong because the script throws out the following error:

> Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus - that helped, but I am not able to work on all the suggestions there but I will figure it out eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var assignments in shell cannot have space chars on either side of `=`, hence  you need

```
 radio=(http://162.253.40.181:8808 http://195.154.69.121:8000 http://108.163.197.114:8103 http://216.245.201.73:9910 http://5.63.145.172:7090)
```

Once you fix that, your line

```
 current = echo $[ 1 + $[ RANDOM % 5 ]]
```

has some problems

Try

```
 current=$(( $RANDOM % 5 ))
```

or if you really need the `1+`, then

```
 current=$(( 1+ $RANDOM % 5 ))
```

AND, per your comment/question, you need

```
mplayer $radio{[$current]}
```

IHTH

Comment: Will radio[current] point to the right element in the array?

Comment: you're correct, that is a problem, see edit at end of my A. Good luck.